# How can apt-get deal with dependency problems associated with a slightly problematic package?

Tags: apt, dependencies

I installed AirVPN in Ubuntu 16.04. Doing so involves meddling with its dependency problems a bit. Now, when I attempt to install Wireshark, I am running into dependency problems for which the solution provided by apt-get is to uninstall AirVPN, which I don't want to do. How can I install both AirVPN and Wireshark in Ubuntu 16.04?

The installation procedure for AirVPN was as follows:

```
wget https://airvpn.org/repository/2.10/airvpn_linux_x64_debian.deb

sudo apt-get -y install gksu
sudo apt-get -y install mono-runtime
sudo apt-get -y install mono-utils
sudo apt-get -y install mono-reference-assemblies-2.0
sudo apt-get -y install openvpn
sudo apt-get -y install stunnel4
sudo apt-get -y install mono-devel

sudo dpkg -i                                       \
    --ignore-depends=libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil \
    --ignore-depends=libmono-winforms2.0-cil       \
    --ignore-depends=libmono-corlib2.0-cil         \
    airvpn_linux_x64_debian.deb
```

The installation attempt for Wireshark is as follows:

```
>sudo apt-get install wireshark
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 airvpn : Depends: libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-winforms2.0-cil but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-corlib2.0-cil but it is not installable
 wireshark : Depends: wireshark-qt but it is not going to be installed or
                      wireshark-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the site bestvpnforyou.

https://www.bestvpnforyou.com/installing-airvpn-client-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-14-04/

If you’ve recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you may have noticed some of the AirVPN dependencies have changed. Whichever LTS version of Ubuntu you’re using you’ll need to install a few dependencies before installing the .deb package, namely some mono packages and openvpn.

The problem right now with installing on Ubuntu 16.04 is a few of the mono dependency packages have been replaced, but the AirVPN .deb download doesn’t recognize them yet.

Here’s a quick rundown of the installation steps for both Ubuntu LTS releases.
For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Bear in mind this is just a temporary and kind of hacky workaround until AirVPN adjusts the dependency requirements in their .deb package. Proceed at your own risk.

1. Download the .deb file from your AirVPN account.
2. Install the newer mono dependency package replacements.

   ```
   sudo apt install gksu mono-runtime mono-utils mono-reference-assemblies-2.0 openvpn stunnel4 mono-devel
   ```
3. Install the Air .deb package you downloaded, BUT you’ll need to tell it to ignore a couple of the older dependency packages that aren’t present in 16.04:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil --ignore-depends=libmono-winforms2.0-cil --ignore-depends=libmono-corlib2.0-cil airvpn_linux_x64_debian.deb
   ```
4. Now you’ll have a problem with dependency errors every time you try to update your system. To get around this, CAREFULLY edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Look for the AirVPN package in that file and remove the above 3 packages from the Depends: line. It should end up looking like this. 
   [image]