# Debian package uninstalled at apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, dpkg

Every time I run `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` airvpn gets removed by default and I need to reinstall it every time.

Can this be avoided?

`apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 airvpn : Depends: libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-winforms2.0-cil but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-corlib2.0-cil but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

`apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglew1.13 libproxychains3 libradare2-0.9.9
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  airvpn
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,389 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I tried to do it manually I know I get this for `apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 airvpn : Depends: libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-winforms2.0-cil but it is not installable
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-system-web4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-system4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 libmono-tasklets4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 4.2.1.102) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 mono-devel : Breaks: libmono-corlib2.0-cil (< 4.0.1~) but 3.2.8+dfsg-10 is installed
 mono-runtime : Depends: mono-runtime-sgen (= 3.2.8+dfsg-10) but 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-8 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How do I get back to the initial state now?

Comment: Well, install the required dependencies... That package is not in the 16.04 repos, so you probably installed it from a .deb file, maybe forcing it via `dpkg`. Is it so? If yes, then you need to do the same with the other packages it depends on.

Comment: If its AirVpn specific, this might be a probable solution:


http://askubuntu.com/questions/825193/how-can-apt-get-deal-with-dependency-problems-associated-with-a-slightly-problem/825202#825202

Comment: How can I force a dpkg remove command ? I just want to get to the previous state

Comment: all good, got to previous state :) . thanks for the link !

Comment: And yes, the solution in the link provided does work !